# Can I use cv.imencode in Opencv.js to export webp images?

Tags: javascript, opencv

I want to transform the format of images from any extension(ex. png, jpg) to **webp**.
So I checked the **OpenCV.js** but I couldn't find **cv.imencode** method to create webp images.
Does it support cv.imencode method?
If not, I will use other server side languages, java, python, etc.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, sadly you cannot do this. there are no image codecs wrapped into opencv.js at all (and the only builtin method to read an image is by grabbing one from a pre-filled canvas)

however, there are 3rdparty js libs like Jimp for this

Comment: Jimp is the library for node.js, isn't it? So I must use some server side language. OK, thanks!